# How to render and interact with a seamless wraparound world map, in the style of e.g. Civ 5, in Godot 3?

Tags: camera, tilemap, maps, godot, terrain-rendering

I asked a similar question on the Godot subreddit but I want to ask here as well in hope of getting more detailed/different answers.

I'm making a world map for a turn-based tile-based 3D strategy game in the style of the Civilization games, and I would like it to have the seamless wraparound in the east-west direction common to this genre of games. The actual map is a finite parallelogram of hexagonal tiles that looks like this:

```
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
  *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
      *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
        *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
          *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
            *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
              *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
                *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
                  *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
```

where each * represents a hexagon.

I need a way for the camera to smoothly start rendering the western part of the map when it nears the eastern edge, and vice versa. The camera is rotatable and zoomable by the player, so I can't rely the map being seen from a fixed viewing angle. I have already implemented a teleporting camera that jumps to the opposite edge when it hits a map edge, but when it is at one edge, half of the screen is currently empty space.

I also need a way to make sure mouse inputs get correctly processed by the game map, even if the player is actually clicking in the "faked" area which is outside the map bounds.

I've gotten previous advice saying to render tiles (or the map as a whole) twice, with the duplicate being to the left or right of the real one, as the camera nears the left or right edge. This is a useful pointer, but it would be helpful for a possible answer to explain how one renders an object in multiple places and how to process user input when the user clicks on the rendered duplicate rather than the real thing.

Also, since first posting this question, I tested a scheme to use 3 cameras, each separated by one map-width in the horizontal direction and have all three of them render with transparent backgrounds. However this method suffers from a Godot rendering bug, and also creates incorrect object draw order where the image from one camera overlaps the next. I'm hoping for an answer which avoids the problems associated with multiple cameras.

Comment: You could treat the rendering and logical positions of a tile as two different things. The hex tiles could be logically connected (some kind of graph structure?) in memory but visually placed anywhere (or in more than one place) in the scene. If you did it this way you could move the tiles around instead of moving the camera around, and wrap the off-screen hexes to whatever side they need to be on.

Comment: @Romen The tiles do store their logical coordinates separate from their 3D position, and something like your suggestion is actually the first method I tried. The problem is that this seriously degrades the game performance (at least the way I know how to do it). It requires checking for each tile each frame whether the tile is too far to one side of the camera and teleporting it to the other side, which also means each tile needs to access the camera's position every frame. If you know any tricks for improved performance with this method I may try reimplementing it.

Comment: Start by rendering each tile twice, like you're rendering the whole map twice side-by side. Then the camera wrap-around is inside the doubled map, like half way through the left copy and half way through the right copy. If this solution works for you then you can tighten it up by rendering only necessary tiles twice to fill in the gaps that the camera can see before it wraps.

Comment: But I need to not only _render_ each tile twice (which I'm not sure how to do) but also make the doppleganger sensitive to mouse and other input, making sure input is neither lost nor doubled. I guess I should edit the question to reflect this, because the comments on another site are also suggesting to render the map twice or three times.

Comment: When you do a mouse click you're usually ray-casting into the scene. If it hits either of the tiles then you would need to do the same thing. Don't think of one as a "fake" tile, they are equals and handle input the same way. If a ray-cast hits either of them then it hits "the" tile.

Comment: @Romen Hm... I guess I need to think about this more, because I'm not sure I understand the process you're describing. In this game engine, the raycast needs a collider to interact with, so it seems like you are suggesting one tile, with 2 colliders and also 2 renderable geometries associated with it. Do I have the right idea?